# F# How to catch all exceptions

Tags: .net, f#, pattern-matching, wildcard, try-with

I know how to catch specific exceptions as in the following example:

```
let test_zip_archive candidate_zip_archive =
  let rc =
      try
        ZipFile.Open(candidate_zip_archive.ToString(), ZipArchiveMode.Read) |> ignore
      zip_file_ok
      with
      | :? System.IO.InvalidDataException -> not_a_zip_file
      | :? System.IO.FileNotFoundException -> file_not_found         
      | :? System.NotSupportedException -> unsupported_exception
  rc
```

I am reading a bunch of articles to see if I can use a generic exception in the `with`, like a wildcard match. Does such a construct exist, and, if so, what is it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I like the way that you applied the *type pattern* test (see [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/pattern-matching)). The pattern you are looking for is called the *wildcard pattern*. Probably you know that already, but didn't realise that you could use it here, too.
The important thing to remember is that the *with* part of a try-catch block follows match semantics. So, all of the other nice pattern stuff applies here, too:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/pattern-matching

Using your code (and a few embellishments so that you can run it in FSI), here's how to do it:

```
#r "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll"
#r "System.IO.Compression.dll"

open System  
open System.IO
open System.IO.Compression

type Status = 
  | Zip_file_ok
  | Not_a_zip_file
  | File_not_found
  | Unsupported_exception
  | I_am_a_catch_all

let test_zip_archive candidate_zip_archive =
  let rc() =
    try
      ZipFile.Open(candidate_zip_archive.ToString(), ZipArchiveMode.Read) |> ignore
      Zip_file_ok
    with
    | :? System.IO.InvalidDataException -> Not_a_zip_file
    | :? System.IO.FileNotFoundException -> File_not_found         
    | :? System.NotSupportedException -> Unsupported_exception
    | _ -> I_am_a_catch_all // otherwise known as "wildcard"
  rc
```

Answer (score 16):

Yes, you can do it like this:

```
let foo = 
  try
    //stuff (e.g.)
    //failwith "wat?"
    //raise (System.InvalidCastException())
    0 //return 0 when OK
  with ex ->
    printfn "%A" ex //ex is any exception 
    -1 //return -1 on error
```

This is the same as C#'s `catch (Exception ex) { }`

To discard the error you can do `with _ -> -1` (which is the same as C#'s `catch { }`)

Comment: This is very helpful. Thanks.